# Android UnsatisfiedLinkError when calling SystemClock.uptimeMillis()

Tags: android

I need to get the phone's up time. To do this, I was calling android.os.SystemClock.uptimeMillis(). However, this throws an UnsatisfiedLinkError. Any ideas on what the issue might be?

Thanks!

Comment: I think the problem is that uptimeMillis() is a native method. Does this mean the C files have to be loaded as well? If so, how is this done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The app had two parts, one that ran on the phone and one that ran on the machine. I was trying to call android.os.systemclock from the app that runs on the computer. Moving it to the daemon that runs on the phone fixed the issue.